# Difference between a ZStack or using .overlay()

Tags: swiftui, overlay, zstack

What is the difference between using a `ZStack` versus using the `.overlay()` modifier.

Apple says:

`ZStack` = "A view that overlays its children, aligning them in both axes."

`.overlay` = "Layers a secondary view in front of this view."

Some examples:

```
ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
    Image(systemName: "folder")
        .font(.system(size: 55, weight: .thin))
    Text("❤️")
}
```

```
Image(systemName: "folder")
    .font(.system(size: 55, weight: .thin))
    .overlay(Text("❤️"), alignment: .bottom)
```

Not considering code size, is there a distinct purpose where one must be used over the other?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

In `ZStack` views are independent on each other and stack fits (if does not have own frame) to biggest view. Also order in ZStack can be modified by using `.zIndex` modifier. All views are in ZStack coordinate space.

In `.overlay` case the view inside overlay always bound to parent view and always *above* parent view (ie. zIndex does not play any role). Also overlaid views are in parent view coordinate space.

The most visible difference is if to make views different size and apply clipping, ie

```
struct TestZStack: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
            Image(systemName: "folder")
                .font(.system(size: 55, weight: .thin))
            Text("❤️").font(.system(size: 55, weight: .thin))
        }
        .clipped()
    }
}
```

gives
[image: demo 1]

```
struct TestOverlay: View {
    var body: some View {
        Image(systemName: "folder")
            .font(.system(size: 55, weight: .thin))
            .overlay(Text("❤️").font(.system(size: 55, weight: .thin)), alignment: .bottom)
            .clipped()
    }
}
```

gives
[image: demo2]