# SwiftUI: How to center align independent of other content in HStack?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have an HStack with content I want left aligned and then `Details` title to be centered.  I am using a `Spacer()` to try and accomplish this but it looks like it's centering `Details` dependent on the content to the left of it.  I would like it to be independent of that and just be centered to the screen. Is that possible using `Spacer()`?

[image]

```
    VStack {
        HStack(alignment: .top) {
            Text("<------")
            Spacer()
            Text("Details")
            Spacer()
        }
        Spacer()         
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible approach is to use overlay, like

```
VStack {
    HStack(alignment: .top) {
        Text("<------")
        Spacer()
    }
    .overlay(
        Text("Details")       // << here !!
    , alignment: .top)
    Spacer()         
}
```

, depending on needs you can place it to root `VStack`

Comment: Any advantage using `.overlay` compared to manually using a `ZStack` ?

Comment: @ClausJørgensen:  I am not in SwiftUI Team but it seems `.overlay` is a product of `ZStack`, I can make a custom `.overlay` modifier from `ZStack`.

Comment: @ClausJørgensen, look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/63446622/12299030