# Swift UI Gradient make Spacer useless

Tags: swift, iphone, xcode, swiftui

I was creating a centered card with a background gradient, I would like to have the height acording with the content, like this:

[image: expected result of card height]

The problem is when I use a gradient component inside the card, because the card height is taking the free space and it is ignoring the Spacer outside of the VStack

```
import SwiftUI

struct TunedModable<Content: View>: View {
    @ViewBuilder var content:() ->  Content
    
    var body: some View {
        
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                
                ZStack {
                    LinearGradient(
                        gradient: Gradient(
                            colors: [.gray, .green]
                        ),
                        startPoint: .bottom,
                        endPoint: .top
                    )
                    VStack {
                        content()
                    }
                }
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                .background()
                .clipShape(
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25.0, style: .continuous)
                )
                
                
                Spacer()
                Text("Testing").foregroundColor(.white)
            }.frame(minWidth:0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity).padding().background(.indigo)
        }
    
}

struct TunedModable_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TunedModable {
            Text("Hello")
        }
    }
}
```

[image]
Result with gradient is a Card with full height but I need to have the height like "automatic" like the first picture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `ZStack` use `background`, like

```
 content()
   .background(
      LinearGradient(
        gradient: Gradient(
            colors: [.gray, .green]
        ),
        startPoint: .bottom,
        endPoint: .top
    ))
```

`ZStack` extended to biggest view (which is Gradient because it does not have own size and consumes all available space), whereas `background` or `overlay` fit to size of target view (`content` in your case).

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/63446622/12299030